# how to calculate from json array and display in view

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

need help this my ajax code theres any one know why my $totprice cannot show into my view

```
public function ajax_basket($kode)public function ajax_basket($kode)
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $list = $this->infobasket->get_by_id3($kode);
    $totprice = 0;
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $infobasket) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = "<td style='width:1px; vertical-align:middle;'><center><p style='font-size:10px;'>".$no."</p><center></td>";
        $row[] = '<td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">'.number_format("{$infobasket->qty}",2,",",".").'</p></center></td>';
        $row[] = '<td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">'.number_format("{$infobasket->price}",2,",",".").'</p></center></td>';
        $row[] = '<td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">'.number_format("{$infobasket->subtotal}",2,",",".").'</p></center></td>';
        $row[] = '<td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">'.number_format("{$infobasket->grandtotal}",2,",",".").'</p></center></td>';          
        $data[] = $row;
        $totprice += $infobasket->price;}
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->infobasket->count_all3($kode),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->infobasket->count_filtered3($kode),
        "data" => $data,
        "totprice" => $totprice,
    );echo json_encode($output);}
```

and this where i want to display in my view where under the table i have input where i want to put my $totalprice

```
    <table id="table_id3" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th style="width:1px; font-size:9px; vertical-align: middle;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">NO</FONT></th>  
              <th style="width:100px; font-size:9px; vertical-align: middle;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">QTY</FONT></center></th><th style="width:100px; font-size:9px; vertical-align: middle;" bgcolor="#00a65a"><center><FONT COLOR="#FFFFFF">PRICE</FONT></center></th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody><tfoot></tfoot></table> 
    <div class="row form-group">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>  
                <div class="col-md-2">              
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-md-1" for="totprice">TOTAL PRICE</label>  
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <input id="totprice" name="totprice" class="form-control input-md" type="text" readonly>
                </div>
    <!-- -->    </ul>
                </div>            
              <!-- /.end box ke 3-->
    </div>
    { table3 = $('#table_id3').DataTable({ 
"serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.         
"searching": false, "orderable": false, "paging": false,"destroy" : true,"orderable": false,     
"processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
"language": {"processing": "<span><img src='images/Preloader_3.gif'/></span>"},
"order": [], //Initial no order.
"ajax": {            
"url": "<?php echo site_url('infopasien/ajax_basket3')?>/" + kode,          
"type": "POST",
"success": function(data) {
 var res = eval(data);// OR var res = JSON.parse(data);
 $('[name="totprice"]').val(res.totprice);//OR $("#totprice").val(res.totprice);
 },}, });}
```

Comment: change $totprice = 0; to $totalprice = 0;

Comment: still not display in view but in array background value show

Comment: can you provide what you get by using echo "<pre>";print_r($output); use it before echo json_encode($output);

Comment: <pre>Array([draw] => 1[recordsTotal] => 2[recordsFiltered] => 2[data] => Array([0] => Array([0] => <td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">1,00</p></center></td>[1] => <td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">70.000,00</p></center></td> [2] => <td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">0,00</p></center></td>[3] => <td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">0,00</p></center></td> )[1] => Array (             
[0] => <td ><center><p style="font-size:10px;">1,00</p></center></td>
) ))

Comment: add $data[] = $totalprice; outside for loop and print array

Answer (score 1):

change from

```
$output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],           
            "data" => $data,);
```

to

```
$output = array(
            "draw" => $_POST['draw'],           
            "data" => $data,
            "totprice" => $totalprice
);
```

Comment: hi dhruv still not show in my view but in output totprice display
draw"1"recordsTotal2recordsFiltered2data[9]0[13]1[13]2totprice496000
how totprice display in my <input id="totprice" name="totprice" class="form-control input-md" type="text" readonly>

Comment: alert(data.totprice);return false; inside "success": function(data)
              {

Comment: in the array totprice show but in my view still not display 
<input id="totprice" name="totprice" class="form-control input-md" type="text" readonly>

Comment: hi dhruv im using ur code the totprice show on my view but alert processing... still loading and not stop

Comment: i have been update my code pls help see my code what wrong why the totprice show but still loading process ajax if i remove "success": function(data) {} the ajax done the data ok but the totprice not display

Answer (score 1):

First put your javascript function inside `<script> <script>`.
Inside your success function try this...

```
"success": function(data)
              {
                var res = eval(data);// OR var res = JSON.parse(data);
                $('[name="totprice"]').val(res.totprice);//OR $("#totprice").val(res.totprice);
              },
```

Comment: hi Hikmat need help
im using ur code the totprice show on my view but alert processing... still loading and not stop

Comment: what is value on `alert(res.totprice);`

Comment: the value is grand total "49000" it show but my qty, price, subtotal not show the ajax still loading process not stop but if remove "success": function(data)
{} my json data will display but the totprice not display i dont know why the process not stop load the json